Set up Zookeeper Stretch cluster in Kubernetes environment
I have one requirement to set up Kafka stretch cluster (we are not using confluent) in 3 Kubernetes environments. Kubernetes clusters will be independent, and they are NOT stretched.
Problem is that zookeepers are not able to connect across kubernetes clusters
I verified following scenario step by step for connectivity test in 2 kubernetes clusters:
** Scenario 1 (with only Zookeeper):
**   i.  Installed 2 kafka brokers and one zookeeper in one kubernetes environment
ii. Installed only one broker in second kubernetes environment
iii. Exposed port 2181, 3888 and 2888 using NodePort
Test: The broker in second kubernetes environment successfully connected with zookeeper of first kubernetes environment
Scenario 2 (With 2 zookeeper)
i. Installed 2 kafka brokers and one zookeeper in one kubernetes environment
ii. Installed one broker and one zookeeper in second kubernetes environment
iii. Exposed port 2181, 3888 and 2888 using NodePort
Error: The Zookeepers are not able to interconnect using port 3888 or exposed nodeport (eg: 30183) across kubernetes.
Question: Can any one please advice me how to set up Zookeeper strecth cluster in kubernetes where kubernetes is not strecthed. Following is my sample file for one environment:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: dc2-zookeeper-cluster
  namespace: kafka  
spec:
  selector:
    app: dc1-zookeeper-cluster
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: client
    port: 2181
    nodePort: 30181  
    targetPort: 2181 
  - name: follower
    port: 2888
    nodePort: 30182
    targetPort: 2188
 - name: leader
    port: 3888
    nodePort: 30183
    targetPort: 3888

zookeeper-deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: dc1-zookeeper
  namespace: kafka  
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: dc1-zookeeper-cluster
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: dc1-zookeeper-cluster
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: dc1-zookeeper-cluster
        app: dc1-zookeeper-cluster
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: zookeeper
        image: bitnami/zookeeper:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 2181
        - containerPort: 2888
        - containerPort: 3888
        lifecycle:
          postStart:
            exec:
              command:
                - "sh"
                - "-c"
                - >
                  echo "1"  > /bitnami/zookeeper/data/myid
        env:
        - name: ZOO_SERVER_ID
          value: "1" 
    - name: ZOO_LISTEN_ALLIPS_ENABLED
      value: "1"    
        - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
          value: "yes"
        - name: ZOO_SERVERS
          value: <<dc1 ip>>:30182:30183,<<dc2 ip>>:30182:30183


It's not clear what you mean by stretched since you're not applying any antiAffinity rules to the StatefulSet... Please try using Strimzi Operator, not manually configured bitnami images. Kafka has also deprecated Zookeeper mode, so I wouldn't recommend trying to get that working

If Kubernetes isn't "stretched", then it's not possible to make Kafka be any different

Strimzi does not support Kafka stretch cluster. And also, we cannot make Kubernetes stretched for project restriction. So I am looking for solution how we can make kafka stretch cluster (zookeeper/Kraft) in two Kubernetes cluster.

Strimzi should support it, if you stretch the k8s cluster itself. IMO, no service will work well across two clusters without adding something like kubefed. You can't use IP addresses since the Zookeeper pods can relocate to different nodes in the cluster... You'll need to setup Ingress Controller for external connections, but those generally only accept HTTP connections, not TCP without additional TLS setup for to resolve service names with SNI

@OneCricketeer - Thanks for reply.  Only Zookeeper ensemble is not working. I tried to set up Kafka stretch cluster based on KRaft model and this is working.

Have you tried prevega/Zookeeper-operator? Kafka will remove Zookeeper in next major release, so I'd suggest staying with Kraft

@OneCricketeer No, I did not try any operator. I will look into that. Thanks for hint. Agreed, I also suggested to use KRaft . But till wanted to know the technical reason behind the connectivity issue on port 3888.  As we are able to connect for KRaft across Kubernetes, so there is no issue for Kubernetes side. It seems that there is issue on zookeeper side. Are we missing to configure any parameter?

The name and selector in the Service spec use different DC. Your ZOO_LISTEN_ALLIPS_ENABLED. variable is not indented correctly in the question, and you should always run an odd number of Zookeepers. And you've defined the StatefulSet, but not mounted any volumes, so data may not be persisted correctly
